# Azure Active Directory, IDX10500: Signature validation failed

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to run this sample to authenticate with Azure Active Directory:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

I authenticate fine, and am redirected to my sample site, and then receive this error:

> IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve
>   SecurityKeyIdentifier

I've researched and don't understand what I need to do on my end with this sample to get this running.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I test that Sample and succeeded. Did you follow the steps in that sample  ?  Do you mind sharing the `Manifest` of the Azure AD Application  and the `Web.config` in your question?

Comment: I did follow every step along the way.  I'll have to ask our admin if I can do that.  Unfortunately, I'm not our Azure admin, and I've run into some permissions issues when trying to do all of this, so I'm wondering if that might be the case in this example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps someone else out, but after getting with a Microsoft support guy and with our Azure administrator, it turned out the app registration was created with SAML instead of OAUTH2 authentication.

Our admin had to delete the app registration in Azure and recreate it with the proper authentication method.  As an Azure user and not an admin, there's nothing in there for me to look at to realize this was the issue.